# variable is not defined when i try to get an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, attr

this is my code: (Im using a CMS based in MVC).

html:

```
 <div class="item_group_title">
  <a id="title_{$group.title}" data-tip="{lang("show", "store")}" class="hide_group"  href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="Store.toggleGroup(this)">
   <img src="{$url}application/images/icons/{$group.title}.png">
  </a>
 </div>
```

...

```
 <section class="item_group" id="group_{$group.title}" {if $minimize}style="display:none"{/if}>
 </section>
```

js:

```
toggleGroup: function(field)
{
    var titleId = $(field).attr('id');
    var groupId = $titleId.text().replace('title_', 'group_');
    var group = $($groupId);

    if(group.is(":visible"))
        {
        $(field).attr('data-tip', lang("hide", "store"));
    }
    else
    {
        $(field).attr('data-tip', lang("show", "store"));
    }

    group.css("display","visible");
},
```

What im trying to get is: When i click on the link the section below should be visible. There will be some links and some sections and each link will be affect one section.

My problem is that i receive this error: $titleId is not defined

Any ideas? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

`titleId` and `$titleId` is not the same thing, the dollarsign is just another character that is part of the variable name.

How about

```
var $titleId = $(field).attr('id');
var $groupId = $titleId.text().replace('title_', 'group_');
var group    = $($groupId);
```

It's the same with a lot of your variables, make sure they either have the dollarsign, or they don't.

Comment: It still sending an error but this time: $titleId.text is not a function,
maybe the syntax is wrong?

Comment: @user3371028 - Nope, `$titleId` is now the ID returned on the line above, which would be just a string, and a string has no `text()` method, so that's sounds right.

Comment: It's a little hard to grok what you're trying to do, but maybe something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/5aXbV/

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I did't explain my code well.
groupId should be and string and the id of the element "group" so

var group should reference an element whose id is groupId

Comment: @user3371028 - Oh, I think I see now, just remove text() if you wan't to replace something in the ID, and do `$titleId.replace('title_', 'group_');`